# How to show the slogan in Olivero?

Tags: 9

I have added a slogan in Olivero but it doesn't appear.

Only the (textual) web site **name** appears.

I went to edit the Site Branding block and under "Toggle branding elements" I have all three elements check-marked (Logo, Site Name and Site Slogan).

Maybe Olivero just don't support slogans, if so, what can be do about that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about a bug that must be handled in the Drupal core issue queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an open bug in Drupal. Use a patch from the issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3188136

Comment: Must I patch or a minor upgrade can be an alternative?

Comment: The bug fix is not yet committed to any development branch. There is no upgrade that would fix this as of today.